# Copy File to a Directory in C

Tags: c, directory, copy

How do you write a program in C that can copy a file (given by source file path, eg. /input/input.txt) into an existed directory? The copy file in the directory must have the exact same name as the input file.

This is the piece of code I have so far:

```
int copyfile1(char* infilename, char* outfileDir) {
FILE* infile; //File handles for source and destination.
FILE* outfile;
DIR* outfileDir;

infile = fopen(infilename, "r"); // Open the input and output files.
if (infile == NULL) {
  open_file_error(infilename);
  return 1;
}

outfileDir = opendir(outfilename);
if (outfile == NULL) {
  open_file_error(outfilename);
  return 1;
}

outfile = fopen(infilename, "w");
```

I get stuck here. I'm not sure how to handle the output file now, since it is supposed to be in the directory. If I use fopen(), it will be create in the current directory only.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use basename(3) -- http://linux.die.net/man/3/dirname

```
int copyfile1(char* infilename, char* outfileDir) {
    FILE* infile; //File handles for source and destination.
    FILE* outfile;
    char outfilename[PATH_MAX];

    infile = fopen(infilename, "r"); // Open the input and output files.
    if (infile == NULL) {
      open_file_error(infilename);
      return 1;
    }
    sprintf(outfilename, "%s/%s", outfileDir, basename(infilename))

    outfile = fopen(outfilename, "w");
```